# How to join two json files in python instead of nesting for loop

Tags: python, json, performance, dictionary, merge

Every time i will get 500 records form file1 to join file2 which contains more than 100000 records  it costs two minutes !!

```
with open(file1,'r') as f1,open(file2,'r') as f2:
    a = json.load(f1)
    b = json.load(f2)
    list_a = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for n in range(len(b)):
            if b[n]["id"] == a[i]["id"]:
                list_a.append(dict(b[n], **a[i]))
with open(result,'w') as f3:
    json.dump(list_a, f3,sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False)
```

File1:

```
[{ "id":"1", "name":"Tom" }, 
{ "id":"2", "name":"Jim" }, 
{ "id":"3", "name":"Bob" }, 
{ "id":"4", "name":"Jeny" },  
{ "id":"5", "name":"Lara" }, 
{ "id":"6", "name":"Lin" }, 
{ "id":"7", "name":"Kim" }, 
{ "id":"8", "name":"Jack" }, 
{ "id":"9", "name":"Tony" }]
```

File 2:

```
[ { "id":"1", "Details":[ { "label":"jcc", "hooby":"Swimming" }, { "label":"hkt", "hooby":"Basketball" }, ] }, 
{ "id":"2", "Details":[ { "label":"NTC", "hooby":"Games" } ] } ]
```

Result:

```
[ { "id":"1", "name":"Tom", "Details":[ { "label":"jcc", "hooby":"Swimming" }, { "label":"hkt", "hooby":"Basketball" }, ] }, 
{ "id":"2", "name":"Jim", "Details":[ { "label":"NTC", "hooby":"Games" } ] } ]
```

Comment: Make one or more dictionaries with ids as keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs in `O(N*M)` time (where `N == len(a)` and `M == len(b)`), which is too slow for such big files. You can make it run in `O(N + M`) time by creating a mapping for `a`'s ids first and using it to find matching `b`'s ids, e.g.:

```
import json

with open('file1') as f1, open('file2') as f2, open('file3', 'w') as f3:
    a = json.load(f1)
    b = json.load(f2)

    aid = {d['id']: d for d in a}
    list_a = [{k: v for d in (b_dict, aid[b_dict['id']]) for k, v in d.items()}
              for b_dict in b if b_dict['id'] in aid]

    json.dump(list_a, f3, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False)
```

If you want the code to be compatible with Python 2.x, you can use a dictionary comprehension to merge dictionaries (like illustrated above). In Python 3.5+ you can simply use [unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), e.g. `{**d1, **d2}`.

Comment: thanks for your replay, i have test scuucess in python3 but python2.7 error:     list_a = [{**items, **a_map[items["id"]]} for items in b if items["id"] in a_map]
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax how can i fix it . Many thanks!

Comment: and then i found python versions < 3.5 do not support starred expressions in dicts but i need do this in python2.7 can you help

Comment: @PythonBeggar: You can use a dictionary comprehension instead of unpacking if you want to stay compatible with Python 2.x (see the update).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the experience to know if this would speed it up. The solution below provided by Eugene Yarmash seems more reliable. I also don't have the big files to test speed, but you can try and see if using collections would speed up the iteration. I'd actually be curious myself if it would change anything:

```
File1 = [ { "id":"1", "name":"Tom" }, { "id":"2", "name":"Jim" }, { "id":"3", "name":"Bob" }, { "id":"4", "name":"Jeny" }, { "id":"5", "name":"Lara" }, { "id":"6", "name":"Lin" }, { "id":"7", "name":"Kim" }, { "id":"8", "name":"Jack" }, { "id":"9", "name":"Tony" } ]
File2 = [ { "id":"1", "Details":[ { "label":"jcc", "hooby":"Swimming" }, { "label":"hkt", "hooby":"Basketball" }, ] }, { "id":"2", "Details":[ { "label":"NTC", "hooby":"Games" } ] } ] 

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)
for l in (File1, File2):
    for elem in l:
        d[elem['id']].update(elem)
Result = dict(d)
```

Comment: thank you for your response ,but we need the data just match file1 ,the result you provide include not have